# Major issue in Boolean Algebra for subtraction of two numbers

Tags: math, binary, logical-operators, binary-data

I was learning how to build a computer ALU, online, and the tutor comes up with a truth table which works perfectly and seems magical. 
One of the tasks was to find `x-y` (both x and y are 16-bit boolean buses)

'+' anywhere is normal binary addition and not 'OR'

On implementing boolean algebra on the truth table `x-y = NOT(NOT(x)+y))`.
It works perfectly and I am not able to understand how it was derived.

here's the truth table:-

*(make sure that both x and y are bus inputs {eg 0101 for 5 and 1011 for -5} also in x+y is normal binary addition and not binary OR, and in x&y '&' is a bitwise AND operator)*

*the numbers in the truth table correspond to the variables zx,nx,zy,ny,f,no and out respectively. You can consider any random number for x and y, just make sure it's a bus. like, if its a 4bit ALU, 2 will be considered as ' 0010' and after using '!' it will become '1101'*

[image]
[image]

I tried deriving the boolean logic myself and I came up with these steps:-

'+' anywhere is normal binary addition and not 'OR'

```
x-y = x+(-y)
-y = NOT(y) + 1    //2's complement
```

therefore,

```
x-y= x+(NOT(y) + 1)
```

and according to the truth table

```
x-y = NOT(NOT(x)+y)
```

How is this working?? Can anyone please tell me how to think on these steps to derive such booleans functions?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about 2 - 1.  Using 3 bits 2 = 010, 1=001, NOT(1)=110,  2 AND NOT(1) = 010 AND 110 = 010 = 2. Or am I missing something.

Comment: oh, I have actually made a mistake in my question. I have considered NOT(NOT(x)+y) as (x) AND ( NOT(y) ) using de morgan's law(It can't be used because '+' is not OR but normal addition instead). BUT even if we consider NOT(NOT(x)+y), how do we reach to this conclusion.

Comment: That seems more reasonable. To get the two's compliment you take the one's complement and add 1. The two complement of x will be -x, the one complement is NOT(x) so -x = NOT(x)+1 or NOT(x) = -1-x. Following though NOT(NOT(x)+y) = NOT(-1-x+y) = -1 - (-1-x+y) = x - y.